# Help with finding the definite integral of $e^{\frac{2x-x^2}{2}}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

[image]

I have this integral that I am trying to evaluate **by hand**, but I am encountering some difficulties. According to Wolfram Alpha, the answer seems to be:

[image]

However, I do not understand how they got the indefinite integral. What integration technique should be used to approach this problem? Could anyone explain how to find the definite integral *with work*? All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to complete the square with the quadratic function in the argument of the exponential first.  Then relate it to an error functions (This integral does not have a closed form anti-derivative in terms of simple functions).

Comment: If you want to integrate $e^{-x^2}$, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Note that $e^{\frac {2x-x^2}{2}}=e^{-\frac {(x-1)^2}{2}}\cdot e^{\frac 12}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we complete the square in the exponent, we have

$$\frac 1 2(2x - x^2) = \frac 1 2 \Big(-(x - 1)^2 + 1\Big) = -\left(\frac{x - 1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2 + \frac 1 2$$

Hence,

\begin{align*}
\int e^{\frac 1 2(2x - x^2)} dx &= \sqrt e \int e^{-\left(\frac{x - 1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2} dx
\end{align*}

Make the change of variables

$$u = \frac{x - 1}{\sqrt 2},\quad \sqrt 2 \, du = dx$$

and we'll find that our integral is

$$\sqrt{2e} \int e^{-u^2} du$$

Unfortunately, there is no closed form for this integral, but it can then be expressed in terms of the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), which is defined to be

$$\operatorname{erf}(t) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^t e^{-u^2} du$$

---

Alternatively, since you *do* have bounds on your integral, you should look at the [Gaussian integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html), which gives that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} du = \sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth answer. This makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: @sameetandpotatoes You're very welcome.